# Proving $L^2$ error estimate for piecewise linear error bounds

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $f(x)$ be a $C^2$ function on $[0,1]$, split uniformly into intervals of length $h=1 / n$. Let $p$ be the piecewise linear polynomial interpolating $f$ on each interval.

I am trying to prove the following $L^2$ error estimate:

$\sqrt{\int_0^1|f(x)-p(x)|^2 d x} \leq h^2 \sqrt{\int_0^1\left|f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right|^2 d x}$

My attempt at the proof is to first show that the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ for $x$ close to zero can be written as
$$
f(x)=f(0)+f^{\prime}(0) x+\int_0^x f^{\prime \prime}(s)(x-s) d s
$$

and then show $$p(x)=f(0)+f^{\prime}(\alpha) x, \alpha \in[0, h]$$

I would use these to results to show $$|f(x)-p(x)| \leq \sqrt{3 h} x\left(\int_0^h\left|f^{\prime \prime}(s)\right|^2 d s\right)^{1 / 2}$$,

and finally show

$$\|f-p\|_{L^2([0,1])} \leq h^2\left\|f^{\prime \prime}\right\|_{L^2([0,1])}$$

Can someone help me with this proof?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use the Taylor formula based in $x$ to get expressions for $f(x_0)$, $f(x_1)$. As per https://math.stackexchange.com/a/610305/115115 you get for the linear interpolation on some interval $[x_0,x_1]$
$$
f(x)=p(x)+\int_{x_0}^{x_1} G(x,s)f''(s)\,ds\tag{GK}
$$
with (using notation 8$a\sqcup b=\max(a,b)$, $a\sqcap b=\min(a,b)$)
$$
G(x,s)=\dfrac{(x_1-x\sqcup s)(x\sqcap s-x_0)}{x_1-x_0}
=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{(x_1-x)(s-x_0)}{x_1-x_0}, & s\in [x_0,x]\\[.5em]
\dfrac{(x_1-s)(x-x_0)}{x_1-x_0}, & s\in [x,x_1]\\
\end{cases}
$$
So via Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
|f(x)-p(x)|^2\le\left(\frac{(x_1-x)^2(x-x_0)^2}{3(x_1-x_0)}\right)\|f''\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}\tag{CS}
$$
and this can now be integrated over the interval
\begin{align}
\|f-p\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
&\le\|f''\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\frac{(x_1-x_0)^2(x-x_0)^2-2(x_1-x_0)(x-x_0)^3+(x-x_0)^4}{3(x_1-x_0)}
\\
&=\|f''\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
\left(\frac{\frac13-\frac12+\frac15}{3}\right)(x_1-x_0)^4
\\
&=\frac{(x_1-x_0)^4}{90}\|f''\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
\end{align}

---

One could avoid this last integration using the AM-GM inequality
$$
\sqrt{(x_1-x)(x-x_0)}\le\frac{(x_1-x)+(x-x_0)}2=\frac{x_1-x_0}2
$$
directly in (CS) to get
$$
|f(x)-p(x)|^2\le\frac{(x_1-x_0)^3}{3·2^4}\|f''\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
\\
\implies \|f-p\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
\le\frac{(x_1-x_0)^4}{48}\|f''\|^2_{L^2[x_0,x_1]}
$$